# Sending data from IBAction in TableViewCell to TableViewViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have a `TableView` with it's own class and a class for the `TableViewCell`. in the `TableView` class I have an `array` which I want to fill with added users, which are added by pressing an add button in the corresponding `TableViewCell`, the way I've solved it now is using the `button.tag = indexpPath.row` and then I've set the array as a global array, which isn't optimal.

So my question is, inside my `IBAction` for the follow button, how can I pass that data to the `TableViewClass` without having to perform a segue?

Note: it's in Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define some "AddUserDelegate" protocol, regadless whether it is swift or objective-c, which the TableViewController implmeents/conforms to.

Then I would add a (weak) reference to the TableViewController - or the protocol respectively - to the TableCellView class and call the protocol's delegate method accordingly within the action of that very button. 
Any additional data required that the button's action has to hand into the protocol's method in order to identify which cell hast been pressed or to which object it refers to etc. I would add as instance variable (weak again if it is a reference) to the custom TableView Class (you have one already) and just pass them though.
As you create your own class anyway there is no reason any more to abuse any view's `tag` property for business logic (for which is is not really intended).